# What is the difference between vector<vector<int>>vec1 and vector<int>vec2[100]?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

What is the difference between `vector<vector<int>>vec1` and `vector<int>vec2[100]` in C++?

Please give me an example for each?

Comment: Did you research to find out what each one means? Then compare the differences in explanations? If so, what did you find and what questions do you have about that? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<vector<int>> vec1
```

is **vector of vector integers**, where the size of **both** `vec1` and its rows (means `vector<int>`) can be resized as per the elements number increases.

for example, you can do

```
vec1.resize(2);     // you have now two rows or two `vector<int>` in it!
vec1[0].resize(3);  // resize or push back as many you want
vec1[1].resize(4);
```

now you have the following in the `vec1`

```
{
  {0, 0, 0},    // vec1[0].
  {0, 0, 0, 0}, // vec1[1]
}
```

Where as

```
vector<int> vec2[100]
```

is **array of vector of integers**, in which you can **only** change the size of array elements (means `vec2[0]`, `vec2[1]`,....), not the array (means `vec2`) itself. The size of the array is fixed, which is 100.

Means, you have (fixed sized) `100` of `vector<int>`. And you can resize them.

for example, when you do

```
vec2[0].resize(3);
vec2[1].resize(4);
```

you get the `vec2` as

```
{
  {0, 0, 0},    // vec2[0].
  {0, 0, 0, 0}, // vec2[1]
  {}, // vec2[3] with no elements in it!
  ....
  ....
  {} // vec2[99] with no elements in it!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

vector<vector>vec1 is [Vector of Vectors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-of-vectors-in-c-stl-with-examples/?ref=rp) and vectorvec2[100] is [Array of Vectors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-of-vectors-in-c-stl/).

[Difference Between C++ Vector and Array](https://www.educba.com/c-plus-plus-vector-vs-array/)

[Advantages of vector over array in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advantages-of-vector-over-array-in-c/)